# How to show that the following function from $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is injective and/or surjective, or neither?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, integers

I have a question that says the following:

> Define $$f(n) = \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1-(-1)^n}{4}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $ f\colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ , where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers. Only one of the following choices is correct. Provide a proof of your choice.
>
> a) $f$ is not a function from $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ because $\frac{n}{2}$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}$
>
> b) $f$ is a function and is onto and one-to-one
>
> c) $f$ is a function and is not onto but is one-to-one
>
> d) $f$ is a function and is onto but is not one-to-one

I know a) is not the answer for sure, because for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we get a map to another integer in $\mathbb{Z}$. So it is a function, but I am having a hard time showing that it is injective and/or surjective. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you compute a table of values for $f(n)$ for some small (including negative) values of $n$, and so gain a feeling for the function?

Comment: Observe that $f(1)=f(2)=1.$ So $f$ is not one-to-one. But $f$ is definitely onto. So $(d)$ is the only correct option.

Comment: To see that $f$ is onto observe that for any $k \in \Bbb Z$ we have $f(2k-1)=f(2k)=k.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $f(2k-1)=f(2k)=k,$ for all $k \in \Bbb Z.$ This shows that $f$ is not one-to-one but definitely onto.

So $(d)$ is the only correct option.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I can see why it is not one-to-one. However, I don't know how to show that it is surjective (onto). I don't know how to get the inverse of the function to show that f(n)=y for any y ∈ ℤ.

Comment: @Nev $f$ is onto because for every $k \in \Bbb Z$ we have $f(2k-1)=f(2k)=k.$ So $f^{-1} (\{k \}) = \{2k-1,2k \}$ for every $k \in \Bbb Z.$

Comment: So I did the following: Let $y= f(n)$. Then $y= \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1-(-1)^n}{4}$ I then tried to solve for n and narrowed it down to $ 4y-1= 2n - (-1)^n$. I want to solve for n, so that I can show that f(n) = y

Comment: Yea, I totally get what you're saying but I need to show that by solving for the inverse and plugging it back in, don't I?

Comment: Take $y \in \Bbb Z.$ Then take $n=2y-1$ or $2y.$ Try to show that $f(n) = y.$ Then you are done.

Comment: @Nev you can do your own manipulation what you have said in your above comment to find the inverse image. But you need to break it into two separate cases where $n$ is odd and where $n$ is even. Then you will end up with the same conclusion what I made.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the clarifications :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92481/discussion-between-nev-and-dbchatto67).